# How to create integer UUID in java

Tags: java, integer, uuid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to generate a random UUID, which consists only of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092970/is-there-a-way-to-generate-a-random-uuid-which-consists-only-of-numbers)

I don't want to have chars in the `UUID` only integers .. how to do that in `java` ?

Comment: Once you do it you cannot call it UUID anymore.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Why not?

Comment: A UUID is *universally* unique, not just unique to your system. A UUID must have letters and numbers. Are you just looking for an integer ID that is unique to *your* system?

Comment: Just use an atomically autoincrement sequence like as DBs have.

Comment: A UUID is a 128-bit *number*. You may represent it with 32 hex digits and 4 hyphens. You may represent it with only `A`s and `B`s - just convert it to binary. You can represent it in BASE64. It's a number!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need 2 `long`s to store a `UUID`.

```
UUID myuuid = UUID.randomUUID();
long highbits = myuuid.getMostSignificantBits();
long lowbits = myuuid.getLeastSignificantBits();
System.out.println("My UUID is: " + highbits + " " + lowbits);
```

Comment: This will potentially have `-` signs.

Comment: @corsiKa: I realize that. This code represents a UUID using 2 integers.

Answer (score 8):

- Use the `getMostSigBits()` and `getLeastSigBits()` to get the long values.
- Then use those long values to populate a `byte[]`.
- Then use that byte[] to make a `BigInteger` object.
- That `BigInteger`'s toString() will be a UUID that may potentially be negative. You can get around that issue by potentially replacing the `-` sign with a 1, ot some other similar technique.

I haven't tested this, but whatevs #gimmetehcodez

```
long hi = id.getMostSignificantBits();
long lo = id.getLeastSignificantBits();
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(16).putLong(hi).putLong(lo).array();
BigInteger big = new BigInteger(bytes);
String numericUuid = big.toString().replace('-','1'); // just in case
```

Comment: You could also fix the negative problem by adding a 0 `byte` in the correct place of the `byte[]`.

Comment: You... you have got to be kidding me. This literally uses the set by step instructions complete with what methods to call and everything.

Answer (score 1):

This will generate a v4 UUID with no characters, however it becomes significantly less unique.

```
final int[] pattern = { 8, 4, 4, 4, 12 };

final int[] versionBit = { 2, 0 }; /* 3rd group, first bit */
final int version = 4;

final int[] reservedBit = { 3, 0 }; /* 4rd group, first bit */
final int reserved = 8; /* 8, 9, A, or B */

Random rand = new Random();

String numericUuid = "";

for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < pattern[i]; j++) {
        if (i == versionBit[0] && j == versionBit[1])
            numericUuid += version;
        else if (i == reservedBit[0] && j == reservedBit[1])
            numericUuid += reserved;
        else
            numericUuid += rand.nextInt(10);
    }

    numericUuid += "-";
}

UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(numericUuid.substring(0, numericUuid.length() - 1));
System.out.println(uuid);
```

You can also brute-force one using the following code:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

while (StringUtils.containsAny(uuid.toString(), new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' })) {
    uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
}

System.out.println(uuid);
```