# Want to generate unique numeric id , can't use node-uuid since backend is expecting numeric id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In 1 of use case , it is possible to add new and edit newly added and existing records for that I am using uuid generator package to generate unique id for new records and then edit using that id by finding it in table ,but that is giving issue since backend webservice is expecting records' id in number and (backend logic is if a record have its id through which record can't be found in DB they would insert new record )and since new records have id as string its giving error , 
is it possible to generate numeric unique id safely

Comment: from your description, you should not be sending the `id` for new records (*it will be automatically generated by the backend*). So check if `id` is a string (*it was created in the frontend*) and strip it before sending it to the backend,.

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092970/is-there-a-way-to-generate-a-random-uuid-which-consists-only-of-numbers

Comment: Thanks a lot it seems to solve my problem  , however since request is failing while submitting , because json parsing is giving error while converting string to long in backend logic , so i think solution you mentioned in which backend logic can convert string uuid to bigint could be a solution , because if we strip in string ids in frontend , then two times iterations over records would happen 1 in frontend as well and 1 in backend while converting DTO to entity , so i think its better to do only in 1 place  only in backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily generate a `unique ID` based on `time` by simply doing:

ES6:

```js
const date = new Date();
const dateValue = date.valueOf();
console.log('uniqueID-> ', dateValue);
```

ES5:

```js
var date = new Date();
var dateValue = date.valueOf();
console.log('uniqueID-> ', dateValue);
```